# Configure Xcode Source Trees from Command Line?

Tags: xcode

We have a project that uses Xcode "Source Trees".

It's important for us to allow people to move these around to use different branches/etc.

However, for a "stock" setup, we can easily determine what the path should be from a script.

I'd like to build a script that does a checkout and setup of a new computer because I'm getting tired of walking through the tedious process of setting up machines manually.

Does anyone know how I can create "Source Trees" in Xcode from a script (simple bash script would be preferred, but I'll use AppleScript if I have to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the plist in question is com.apple.dt.Xcode

so you can say:

```
defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

and it will parse and print Xcode's preferences.

the key in question is `IDEApplicationwideBuildSettings`.

If you have a few defined, you may see something like:

```
IDEApplicationwideBuildSettings =     {
    "MON_SOURCE_ROOT" = "/Volumes/Dir/Dir/Dir/";
    "MON_THIRD_PARTY_SOURCE_ROOT" = "/Volumes/Dir/Dir/ThirdParty/";
};
```

now, you can use the `write` option of `defaults` to set or remove the values using the command line.

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEApplicationwideBuildSettings THE_ARRAY_OF_KEY_VALUE_PAIRS
```

Where `THE_ARRAY_OF_KEY_VALUE_PAIRS` is the value to set it to.

You may also need to update `IDESourceTreeDisplayNames` to create an alias:

```
IDESourceTreeDisplayNames =     {
    "MON_SOURCE_ROOT" = "MON_SOURCE_ROOT";
    "MON_THIRD_PARTY_SOURCE_ROOT" = "MON_THIRD_PARTY_SOURCE_ROOT";
};
```

Work on a copy until you figure out the exact command.